# How to solve the problem with socket not sending messages to specific channels?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, websocket, flask-socketio

I'm trying to write a flask chat with channels. It works perfectly well, but only with the argument 'broadcast' set to True in sending messages. As soon as I change 'broadcast=True' to 'room=room' in @socketio.on('send message'), it stops sending messages at all. When i click send button, nothing happens, nothing is displayed. Could anyone point out what's the problem here? I spent many days on that, I'll appreciate all sort of hints. Thank you.

Server:

```
@socketio.on('join')
def on_join(room):
    print(f"joined channel is: {room}")
    username = session.get("name")
    join_room(room)
    data = {"username": username, "room": room}
    emit('join', data)


@socketio.on('send message')
def handleMessage(data):
    # get user's name and sent message
    print(f"sent data is: {data}")
    message = data["message"]
    name = data["name"]
    date = data["date"]
    room = data["room"]
    print(f"room is: {room}")
    # save data into messages dict   
    messages[room].append(message)

    emit("announce message", {"message": message, "name": name, "date": date},
    broadcast=True)
```

Client(from channels.html, where users click on links redirecting them to specific channel template):

```js
// set onclick funtion to dynamically created elements with jinja2
document.getElementById("all-channels").addEventListener(
    "click", 
    event => {
        if (event.target && event.target.matches("button")) {
            alert("every single button should fucking work");
            const room = event.target.innerHTML;
            alert(room);
            socket.emit('join', room);
        }
    }, 
    false
);
```

Client(from channel.html, a specific channel template, from which messages are being sent):

```js
// configure 'send' button to emit 'send message' event
document.querySelector("#submit-message").onclick = (data) => {
    const message = document.querySelector("#message").value;
    const room = document.querySelector("#specific-channel").innerHTML;
    const name = localStorage.getItem("name");
    var date = new Date();
    date = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear() + ' ' + '|' + ' ' + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes();
    socket.emit(
        'send message', 
        {"message": message, "date": date, "room": room, "name": name}
    );
                        console.log(room);
};
              
                    
// when message is sent, add it to ul
socket.on(
    'announce message', 
    data => {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        const name_test = data.name;
        li.innerHTML = `(${data.date} ${data.name}: ${data.message})`;
        document.querySelector("#messages").append(li);
        document.querySelector("#message").value = "";
        console.log(data);
   }
);
```

No errors are thrown. Console.log and alerts show outputs as I expect them to.

Comment: Have you looked at log output from server and client to see where are the messages getting lost? Unfortunately you are not providing a complete app, so I can't debug this for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I still have no idea why, but it's been working properly since I deleted broadcast=True and room=room from  emit("announce message", {"message": message, "name": name, "date": date}, broadcast=True). It send messages to channels but only without these arguments.